# PHP finding out if words are contained in a large array

Tags: php, arrays, words

I need to check if an array of words ($words) is present in a larger array ($dictionary).
If all the words are there, no errors.
If one or more are not included in $dictionary, I want to send out an error message.
So far, I have come up with this:

```
<?php
// first I select a column from a MySQL table and retrieve 
//all the words contained in that field.
$spell = "SELECT * FROM eventi WHERE utente='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
$qspell = mysql_query($spell) or die ("Error Query [".$spell."]");
while ($risu = mysql_fetch_array($qspell)){
    $risu = mysql_fetch_array($qspell);
    // the following lines remove parentheses, digits and multiple spaces
    $desc = strtolower($risu["descrizione"]);
    $words = explode(" ",$desc);
    $words = str_replace("(","",$words);
    $words = str_replace(")","",$words);
    $words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/','',$words);
    $words = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$words);
    // the array $dictionary is generated taking a long list
    //of words from a txt file
    $dictionary = file('./docs/dizionario.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach($words as $k => $v){
        if (in_array($v, $dictionary)){
            //Do something?
        } else {
            $error = "error";
            echo "The word ".$v." can't be found in the dictionary.";
        }
    }
}
if (!isset($error)){
    echo "All the words are in the dictionary.";
} else {
    echo "There are some unknown words. See above.";
}
?>
```

This code always returns one single error message, without reporting which word can't be found.
On top of that, words which are actually missing are not detected.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I am aware of this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can we get the error?

Comment: It simply returns `The word can't be found in the dictionary.` (only once, and as you can see `$v` is empty).

Comment: What does your `$words` array look like ? Try doing `var_dump($words)` maybe ?

Comment: Also, try to make sure that `$dictionary` has valid values as well.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` o a value fetched from the database?

Comment: Here is what `$words` look like: `array(6) { [0]=> string(8) "riunione" [1]=> string(2) "di" [2]=> string(14) "programmazione" [3]=> string(8) "triennio" [4]=> string(3) "con" [5]=> string(8) "colleghi" }`

Comment: You are right. I removed that.

Comment: Are you sure the file is being loaded properly?

Comment: Yes: **http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php**

Comment: Look at array_diff()

Comment: Using `array_diff()` it returns a series of empty arrays and then this: `Array ( [4] => ) Array ( [4] => ) Array ( [4] => ) Array ( [4] => ) Array ( [4] => ) Array ( [4] => )`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem lies at the line:

```
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/','',$words);
```

Removing digits somehow messes the whole matching procedure.

Without removing digits, my code works.